Combine sine and cosine-terms
I'm new to Stack-Exchange and this is my first question.
I'm facing a problem that orginates from a trigometric task. Here's a sketch:

Essentialy, I have a circle with radius $L$ and a point moving on this circle. There is another point on the end of a tangent from the circle at 3 o'clock-positon downwards-direction (Distance $z_{1}$). This point is fixed. I want to calculate the angle $\alpha$ from a given distance ($z_{2}$) between the moving point and the fixed point.
To find an equation, I introduced a new triangle, shown in red:

With the Pythagorean theorem, I get this equation:
$$(L\sin(\alpha)+z_{1})^{2}+(L(1-\cos(\alpha)))^{2} = z_{2}^{2}$$
Since $L$ and $z_{1}$ are given as constants, and $z_{2}$ is my desired input, I now have a function with only one unkown variable. It is now easy to calculate the angle from a given $z_{2}$ but I want to do it the other way around. To do so, I tried to rearrange my equation to $\alpha$. This it the best I could get so far:
$$z_{1}\sin(\alpha)-L\cos(\alpha) = \frac{z_{2}^{2}-z_{1}^{2}-2L^{2}}{2L}$$
So my question is how can I combine the terms on the LHS of the equation to have only one $\alpha$-expression?
Thanks in advance!

Welcome to MSE. Well done on getting the majority of your formatting done. A couple of useful commands: \times gives the $\times$ symbol and for sine and cosine, try \sin{angle} for improved formatting. I'm looking at your question now and will post an answer if I get to it before others do...

I see. Thank you for the hints on my formatting. I'll take that into account for my next questions. Someone already made thecorrections in the meantime for this post.

Let $\theta = \arctan\dfrac{z_1}{L}$.
Then
$z_1 = \sqrt{z_1^2 + L^2} \sin\theta$
and
$L = \sqrt{z_1^2 + L^2} \cos\theta$,
so
\begin{align}
z_{1}\sin(\alpha)-L\cos(\alpha)
&= \sqrt{z_1^2 + L^2} (\sin\theta\sin(\alpha) - \cos\theta\cos(\alpha)) \\
&= -\sqrt{z_1^2 + L^2} \cos(\alpha + \theta).
\end{align}

The technique I used above is a common technique for a linear combination of the sine and cosine of an angle: find an angle such that the coefficients of the sine and cosine ($z_1$ and $L$ in this example) are themselves proportional to the sine and cosine of some other angle,
then use the angle addition/subtraction formulas to convert the combination of trig functions to a single sine or cosine function.
A simple way to find an angle such that $z_1$ and $L$ are proportional to its sine and cosine (in either order) is to construct a right triangle with legs $z_1$ and $L$. Then the angle you want is one of the non-right angles. Compute the length of the hypotenuse, and you can then read off the sine and cosine of your chosen angle.
In this case I chose the angle in such a way as to come up with the cosine of a sum of angles. The inspiration for that was this figure:

I added a line from the center of the circle (labeled $C$)
to the non-moving point (labeled $B$) on the tangent line.
Now the moving point $A$ and these two fixed points are the vertices of a triangle whose three sides are either known ($c = AB = z_2$ and $b = AC = L$)
or easy to compute ($a = BC = \sqrt{z_1^2 + L^2}$)
and we can apply the Law of Cosines to the angle
$\angle ACB = \alpha + \theta$:
$$ c^2 = a^2 + b^2 - 2ab \cos(\alpha + \theta). $$

Thanks a lot! That solved my issue! Out of curiosity: How did you come up with the genral idea?

Impressive! Thank you, once again!
